# (from ...main import Block) ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: python, import, package

I have the following directory structure:

```
src
├── main.py
└── world
    └── terrain
        └── main.py
```

In `src/main.py` I have a `Block` class that I want to import to `src/world/terrain/main.py`.

I tried to import it this way:

`from ...main import Block`

I use VS Code as my code editor, and when I select the `Block` class and click "Go to Declaration", it sends me to where the code for the class is, in `src/main.py`. **Which is correct.**

*However*, when I try to run my program I get this following error:

```
 line 15, in <module>
    from ...main import Block
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Try putting an `__init__.py` in `src`.

Comment: @MattDMo Nothing changed. Still the same error

Comment: How are you calling the module? Python often doesn't recognize packages if their sub modules are called directly